# web service call performance improvements in dynamics crm 2013

Tags: jquery, performance, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working with MS Dynamics CRM 2013. I have created a HTML we resource and included in one of the entity form. This web resource contains a Javascript method which call an external 3rd party web service and fetch data from it.

I have used jquery ajax method to call web service, however it takes time to load the entire form of that CRM entity. The UI gets unusable for some seconds.

Can we improve the performance in this aspect ?

Comment: make the call asynchronous

Comment: There are some checks on the returned data. Making it asynchronous is causing unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling the service synchronously, don't unless you have a very good reason to do so.  Do the work with the returned data in a callback or better still use a jQuery [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/).

Is the service itself slow?  Measure time to first byte (TTFB) latency, if this is long the service itself is slow.  In a dev environment this might be because the service isn't being accessed and if hosted in IIS the app pool will be recycled.  Each initial request will therefore pay the performance price of warm up.  If the form is also doing a lot of work on load that doesn't depend on the data from the service it's even more important you allow this to execute in parallel by calling the service asynchronously.